# Gitlab windows Runner lastcontact showing never

Tags: windows, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

We have installed Enterprise edition GITLAB.
We have configured the shared runner but it showing the last contact as never.

When I try to run the `gitlab-runner install` command throwing error
like 
 `'gitlab-runner' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

our Gitlab version is 11.2.0

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: have you added the path environment variable?
%PATH%C:\Program Files\Git\bin

Comment: Adding a path variable...
https://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/features/test-runners/add-path-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

**Use command line to add the correct path Environment variable**

```
set PATH=%PATH%C:\Program Files\Git\bin
```

Comment: yes, I  have added but no use. Git is working fine in my system. I have configured windows binaries for the runner from the system. I have followed [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html).While registering runner I choseed shell as the option

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I missed one key step while registering the runner.

```
gitlab-runner register
```

Now the runner is up and working.